How to configure k3s with ingress-nginx to correctly forward user IP in X-Real-IP header?
I am trying to configure k3s with ingress-nginx on some VPS from Hetzner. I have set up a server with a public IP and others without public IPs, all connected in a private network. When I install ingress-nginx on my ingress-nginx-controller, I see EXTERNAL-IP like 10.0.0.6,<public-ip>. Why is this happening?
The problem is that with this configuration, I don't receive the user IP in the X-Real-IP header, I recevie something like 10.42.0.18, even though I have configured externalTrafficPolicy: Local. When I use only the master, I receive the user IP correctly in the X-Real-IP header.
Is there any way to configure it to use only my public IP? Or how can I get the X-Real-IP header to show the user IP?
